# Virtual Box ssh not working on Virtual Box Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed, and 12.04 Server set up in my virtual machine.

My VM has internet access, and I can ping it from my host.

```
ping symfony.dev # points to 192.168.56.101, and successful ping.
```

The problem is that I can't connect to it using SSH

```
me@ubuntu:~$ ssh root@symfony.dev
ssh: connect to host symfony.dev port 22: Connection refused
me@ubuntu:~$ ssh -p 21 root@symfony.dev
ssh: connect to host symfony.dev port 21: Connection refused
```

There doesn't seem to be an IP conflict, if I close the machine I can't ping the address anymore.

SSH is installed on the VM (I did try `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`, but it seems this package doesn't exist, only `openssh-client` - which is already installed, and ssh works from VM).

Any ideas on how I can get this to work ?

**Solution:**

I needed to install `openssh-server`, but cound't do this without `sshd`.

```
sudo apt-get install sshd # next line won't work until you do this
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: If memory serves, the server and client bundle is installed with `apt-get install ssh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. From within the VM, can you ssh to localhost? If not, check your ssh server.
2. If you **aren't** using bridged mode for networking, you may need to access VirtualBox settings and forward port 22. [This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) has instructions and screenshots.
3. Is there a firewall running on the VM? Ubuntu ships with [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW), so try `ufw status` first, before tinkering with `iptables`.

Comment: The problem was #1, it seems I had to install `sshd` before `openssh-server`, or else it doesn't work, or even appear in the autocomplete list. Thanks !

Comment: Just as a side note, the other 2 options are very good to know. I was using bridge mode for networking, and ufw was disabled

Comment: Option 2 helped me. I was on Nat mode