# scp from ubuntu virtual machine under Windows 7: connect refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

This question is similar to [Virtual Box ssh not working on Virtual Box Ubuntu machine](https://superuser.com/questions/582571/virtual-box-ssh-not-working-on-virtual-box-ubuntu-machine?rq=1]). I actually got ssh to work, but now I want to transfer a file from my local machine to the remote machine using scp.

The command

```
scp myLocalAccount@localIP:~/filename remoteUserName@remoteIP:~/path
```

leads to the error

```
ssh: connect to host (localIP) port 22: Connection refused
```

My local machine is a virtual Ubuntu machine running under VMWare in a Windows 7 native environment.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another transfer method I could try?

Comment: Why are you trying to SSH to yourself? Aren’t you trying to copy a local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transfer a local file to the remote system use the following:

```
scp ~/filename remoteUserName@remoteIP:~/path
```

Don't put your local userid and system before the name of the file you want to transfer.